# Suitable library/plugin that removes unused CSS in React

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, styles, css-loader

I have been doing some research to find the most suitable CSS library for my React app that would remove (the 96% of my `bundle.css`) unused CSS.

I realized that most libraries need specific paths to the CSS files to be removed and maybe a whitelist of what should be kept. However, it's trickier in a React app, because there is:

- an SCSS file for each custom component
- a 3rd party CSS library (antd)
- CSS that is runtime-generated

Are there any libraries that allow to do this (hopefully without going through a headache to configure them)?

P.S: I use `webpack` and `mini-css-extract-plugin`